# Howto make SimpleWebRTC Directly Connect to my Websocket URL

Tags: websocket, webrtc, simplewebrtc

By default, [SimpleWebRTC](https://github.com/andyet/SimpleWebRTC) uses https://sandbox.simplewebrtc.com:443/ as its signaling server. Now, this is an XHR endpoint, and somehow, signal master seems to switch it to a web socket connection.

Now, I’m trying to use my own signaling server with SimpleWebRTC. And it’s a straightforward websocket endpoint. So when creating the SimpleWebRTC object, I have `SimpleWebRTC { “url” : ”ws://<my-IP>/chatroom" ...}`

But upon creating the SimpleWebRTC object, it proceeds to try and connect to a different URI: **http://my-IP/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1450985796761-0**.

How can I get SimpleWebRTC to just connect directly to **ws://my-IP/chatroom**, and have those parameters just passed along to other peers as signal master does? Does my signaling server have to do anything other than pass along the parameters / message that the initiator sends?

Answer (score 1):

SimpleWebRTC uses socket.io instead of raw websockets. If you want to use raw websockets you can try replacing https://github.com/andyet/SimpleWebRTC/blob/master/socketioconnection.js with your raw websocket connection.

Or you implement the socket.io protocol in your server.

Comment: ***A)*** On the **client**, there doesn't seem to be a direct (configurable) way to override SimpleWebRTC's use of [socket.io](http://socket.io) (ex: in [simplewebrtc.bundle.js](https://github.com/andyet/SimpleWebRTC/blob/master/simplewebrtc.bundle.js), overriding the **SocketIoConnection.prototype.[*]** functions wouldn't seem to work (*socket.io-client* is still being [pulled in](https://github.com/andyet/SimpleWebRTC/blob/master/simplewebrtc.bundle.js#L834))).

Comment: ***B)*** On the **server**, would implementing the socket.io protocol basically mean replicating this [block of code](https://github.com/andyet/signalmaster/blob/master/sockets.js#L13-L129)? I'm not using JS on the server, so incoming messages would have to map to the `io.sockets` and `client` objects.

Comment: On the client, you would have reimplement socketioconnection and pass it to the SimpleWebRTC constructor.
Alternatively, on the server you could search for a socket.io implementation in the language you are using. The socket.io protocol is not really documented but popular enough that some implementations exist.

Comment: Hrmm, did a bit of research, and it seems socket.io [isn't the best solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/YWoQCuk2pWA) for Clojure or Java based applications. For now, I'll just use SimpleWebRTC's default signaling server. After that, I'll just have to either ***i)*** implement the socket.io back-end or use ***ii)*** raw RTCPeerConnection objects. Cheers.

Comment: @Nutritioustim you don't have to do either of those things. Just use a websocket and replace the `connection` object passed into SimpleWebRTC to use your. Much, much easier.

Comment: @xdumaine Just tried that, and [SimpleWebRTC](https://github.com/andyet/SimpleWebRTC/blob/master/simplewebrtc.bundle.js#L16) and its containing [SocketIoConnection](https://github.com/andyet/SimpleWebRTC/blob/master/socketioconnection.js#L4) class, require a socketio thing. Dug around in both classes, and there doesn't seem to be a way to pass in just a raw ws object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is signal master for your question:
[github signalmaster](https://github.com/andyet/signalmaster)

For run it, you must to install module of npm in server.js file.
Replace:

```
https://sandbox.simplewebrtc.com:443/ 
↓
http://<yourip>:8888/
```

But I don't understand, if we using that signal server, can we increase performance of frame rate and speed, and no need stun and turn server of google? When I deployed that signalserver on my cloud host? BTW, I can't understand when reading config for install turnserver on github.